# how to count instances in each statement in Grails?

Tags: grails, each, criteria

`Status` domain has many `like`
`like` belongs to `user` and `status`
`user` has many `status` and `like`

I need to show count of `likes` a `status` has.

```
 <g:each in="${statusInstanceList}" status="i" var="statusInstance">
 ${fieldValue(bean: statusInstance, field: "statusMessage")}

 <g:each var="likeInstance" in="${statusInstance.like}">
   ${likeInstance.count()} //this is the where likes should be counted via dynamic finders
 </g:each>

 </g:each>
```

Also please suggest if I am doing this the right way. If not please put me on to the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${statusInstance.like?.size()}` should give the number of `likes` per `status`.

```
......
<g:set var="likesSize" value="${statusInstance.like?.size()}"/>
<g:each var="likeInstance" in="${statusInstance.like}">
   $likesSize
</g:each>
.......
```

Makes sense?

Comment: would you also suggest how to set like and unlike of the status depending on whether user has liked it already or not?
do i need to use criteria or dynamic finder or each loop in gsp to find out like and unlike?
@dmahapatro

Comment: @desicreatioNZ This may be a question totally different from the context of this question. It will be great and helpful to others as well if you can elaborate your question with proper use case and examples as a new question so that can be answered structurally by anyone in the community. I hope I am making sense about not cluttering  this question. :)